# Glowing effect Pulsating glow effect on PNG

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get this effect [image: Glowing gif] from this picture [image] with css and javascript if needed. I experimented with brightness and contrast but I was not able to get the result.

Comment: Why don't you post some code. I mean you should give the timing when does brightness/contrast change when to make a transition from one state to another ect..

Comment: changing css style from one to another is not a problem, getting an effect with css like this is a problem.

Comment: Edit the image with glow. Use animation to switch between states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS filters will do this.

Support however, is not great : [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

```css
img {
  -webkit-animation: glow .25s alternate infinite;
  animation: glow .25s alternate infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
    filter: brightness(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(2);
    filter: brightness(2);
  }
}
@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
    filter: brightness(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(2);
    filter: brightness(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUqANt.png" alt="" />
```